# change existing css attribute and use it by removing or adding the css element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question about changing existing css attribute.
I use Jquery in my html codes.

I would like to know how to change a existng css class attribute and apply changed class to other element.

thanks for concerning my question.

★ css code example

```
.AccentColor{color:#fff;background:#000;}
```

★ javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.AccentColor').css('background','yellow');
$('#target').addClass('AccentColor');
});
</script>
```

★ html

```
<p id="target"> still background color is #000, not yellow.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to your problem is to simply switch the order of your jquery functions:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#target').addClass('AccentColor');
$('.AccentColor').css('background','yellow');
});
</script>
```

Explanation:

You have to add the class to your target first before you can manipulate the css on it. In fact, if you switch your jquery selector to #target instead of .AccentColor, the code will work as you're expecting. In this case, you could easily rewrite it using jquery chaining to keep it a little cleaner.

```
$('#target').addClass('AccentColor').css('background','yellow');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found another solution. My problem was due to missed sequence about assigning variable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the dot from the class name passed to the addClass function

```
$(selector).addClass("classname")
```

Make sure you're using the right classname. In your case AccentColor

Comment: sorry. I had a miss-spelled text. My question is not focussing syntex error, but how to change existing css attribute. I can change the attribute if I change their order such as _$('#target').addClass('AccentColor');    $('.AccentColor').css('background','yellow');_ . However, I need to find the way which can changing existing css attribute in order to apply method, addClass or removeClass.......

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found another solution. My problem was due to missed sequence about assigning variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the css to all elements with the class "AccentColor", which do not exist. And then you are adding a class "Accent" to an element that does exist, however the class "Accent" is not defined in your css. Try this:

```
$('#target').addClass('AccentColor'); //notice no dot "." is needed here.
```

Comment: sorry. I had a miss-spelled text. My question is not focussing syntex error, but how to change existing css attribute. I can change the attribute if I change their order such as _$('#target').addClass('AccentColor');    $('.AccentColor').css('background','yellow');_ . However, I need to find the way which can changing existing css attribute in order to apply method, addClass or removeClass.......

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found another solution. My problem was due to missed sequence about assigning variable. Thanks.